# Can Crystal Reports be exported as pdf and excel independently on button click in Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, excel, pdf, crystal-reports

I have to export my database records into pdf and excel.Exporting option i need to perform on separate button clicks i.e if i click `export2Excel` button excel file should be generated with `OpenWithSaveAs Dialogue box` and vice versa.I know that in web its possible but have no idea in Windows Form Application.
Is this possible in windows form application using C# .Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

```
Response.Buffer = false;
Response.ClearContent();
Response.ClearHeaders();
oRpt.ExportToHttpResponse(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat,Response,true,"COUNTRIES");
```

Also check references [here](http://www.beansoftware.com/asp.net-tutorials/export-crystal-reports-to-pdf.aspx) and [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/ExportCRtoPDF10062006161918PM/ExportCRtoPDF.aspx).